# Need Help Turning Circuit Off When Current / battery Gets Too Low

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi, roomba

Big newbie here.... I had a quick question on where I should look if I want to design a switch that reacts to current / battery level? i.e. current above a certain level, circuit on, current below that level, circuit off.

I have a raspberry pi attached to a roomba for automated control. The raspberry pi is connected to the battery with a 5V regulator going to a USB. It works fine, but if it doesn't get back to the base in time the pi ends up draining the battery completely. I would like to make a circuit that turns a switch off when the voltage gets too low.

Any ideas on where I should start? Or is the whole thing dumb to begin with? lol

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try a little research with other things that detect when your battery is low and there are a lot of ways to do this, i.e. voltage comparison. You shouldn’t be measuring current.

Comment: Battery supervisor ICs. (and you want to turn off when voltage is too low, not current)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help guys! I think I'll try looking into voltage comparators and ICs